# pan home screens programatically in android

Tags: android, navigation, homescreen

I am trying to design an app to navigate to home screen on click of a button and then scroll left or right switching between all layers programatically.I am able to go to home screen using intent but am not able to scroll through the screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, not all home screen implementations have "layers" or "screens". There are thousands of home screen implementations available for Android, both pre-installed on devices and available through places like the Play Store.

Second, your app cannot inject user input events into other apps, except perhaps on rooted devices.